# How can I limit an Artifactory aql query to a specific repository?

Tags: artifactory, artifactory-query-lang

I have this working aql query:

```
items.find({"@myproperties.fileType":{"$match": "myFile"},"@myproperties.otherType":{"$match": "thisType"}})
```

It returns all the results I expect. However, this query looks for files containing these properties in every repository.
How can I limit the search to a specific repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the format needed:

```
items.find({"repo":{"$eq":"myrepo"}}, {"$and":[{"@myproperties.fileType":{"$match": "myFile"}},{"@myproperties.otherType":{"$match": "thisType"}}]})
```

This query language isn't very intuitive, but there it is.